# Security implications when Certificate Authority signed a CSR

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Lets say I submit a CSR with a domain name that is not mine `www.google.com` and CA approved it.

I always wonder how CA validate that I am the owner and approve. Obviously this will definitely get rejected, but it doesn't stop me from impersonating other less well know domain name right?

What are the security implications if CA approved an impersonator?

Answer (score 0):

All commercial CAs have so-called Registration Authority that performs requester's identity check and use various mechanisms to determine if you are eligible to request a certificate for specified domain. One of such checks may include special DNS entry in the domain's DNS zone. Depending on provider other checks may be conducted. Therefore, even for less-known domain names you have to prove that you own or are delegated for that domain by an owner. It is not easy to force CAs to misissue the certificate. It is for domain-validated certificates. More details on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority#Validation_standards

Additional checks are made for organization-validated certificates, where you have to supply a copy of documents that prove your permissions. And even more extensive checks are made for EV certificates.

Implications are simple: you can conduct a MITM attack if you can redirect user traffic to your web server with misissued certificate. However, it will have a huge negative impact on CA repute, therefore CA tend to perform checks properly to save their repute and potential clients.